# Emacs: tab-line-mode, group buffers by extension

Tags: emacs, tabs

I like [tab-line-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tab-Line.html), but I want to display only the tabs related to my work, usually those buffers have the extension **.rb**, **.clj**. or **.coffee**.

tab-line mode has the function **tab-line-tabs-function**, which allows group buffers, so I was thinking to do something like:

```
(setq tab-line-tabs-function #'group-by-buffer-extensions)

(defun my/group-by-buffer-extensions ()
 "Use these extensions to group buffers"
 (interactive)
 (let
   ((my-current-buffers (list (buffer-list)))
    (myExtensions '(".coffee" ".clj" ".rb")))
 (mapcar (lambda (arg) (member (file-name-extension arg) myExtensions)) my-current-buffers)
))
```

but I don't know eLisp enough to finish this function (I don't know what "interactive" means). So, is there a function to create a list based in a list of extensions?

I know I can use Projectile to group files, but I don't know that package either. I just need a filtered list of current buffers.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know eLisp enough to finish this function

Try this version:

```el
(require 'subr-x)

(defvar my/group-by-buffer-extensions
  '("coffee" "clj" "rb")
  "Filename extension list used by function `my/group-by-buffer-extensions'.")

(defun my/group-by-buffer-extensions ()
  "Group buffers according to variable `my/group-by-buffer-extensions'.
Used as a value for `tab-line-tabs-function'."
  (delq nil
        (mapcar (lambda (buf)
                  (when-let* ((filename (buffer-file-name buf))
                              (ext (file-name-extension filename)))
                    (and (member ext my/group-by-buffer-extensions)
                         buf)))
                (buffer-list))))

(setq tab-line-tabs-function #'my/group-by-buffer-extensions)
```

Although I'd actually write that function like this, so that we're only accumulating the list items we need (avoiding pushing all those `nil` items onto the list, and the resulting `delq` pass to get rid of them again):

```el
(defun my/group-by-buffer-extensions ()
  "Group buffers according to variable `my/group-by-buffer-extensions'.
Used as a value for `tab-line-tabs-function'."
  (let (bufs)
    (dolist (buf (buffer-list))
      (when-let* ((filename (buffer-file-name buf))
                  (ext (file-name-extension filename)))
        (when (member ext my/group-by-buffer-extensions)
          (push buf bufs))))
    (nreverse bufs)))
```

> I don't know what "interactive" means.

Refer to the manual:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Using Interactive`

(but I removed it from the function definition, as I don't think you'd need it here.)